# <ul style="list-style-image: url('https://domainname/image/list.png');">

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to list style ul li image from url because sent to email. How can I do this?

This is will be preview in email

```
emailmessage=emailmessage&"<ul style='margin:0 !important;padding:0 0 0 15px !important;list-style-image: url('https://domainname/image/list.png');'>"
emailmessage=emailmessage&"<li style='padding:0 0 10px 5px !important;'>Hallo</li>"
emailmessage=emailmessage&"</ul>"


<ul style="margin:0 !important;padding:0 0 0 15px !important;list-style-image: url('https://domainname/image/list.png');">
<li style="padding:0 0 10px 5px !important;">Hallo</li>
</ul>
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: i adding a new information, edit the question, thank you for your reply

Comment: Basically **don't**. The image would only be seen if the receiver of the email has internet access. Pick another method.